# javascript replace text inside of parenthases

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace text inside of parenthases with the same text surrounded by `<span class="bold">my text between parenthases</span>`

```
text.replace(/\[([^\][]+)]/g, "<span class='font-weight-bold underline'>$1</span>")
```

so If I have `this is my [name]`
It replaces it to `this is my <span class="bold">name</span>`

I need something similar for parentheses.

How can I replace text globally between parentheses? It's not a simple as I thought it would be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: How is that a duplicate? I'm not parsing HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your regex with `text.replace(/\(([^\][]+)\) */g, "<span class='font-weight-bold underline'>$1</span>");`

Comment: Sorry Something's not right there `Invalid regular expression: /\(([^\][]+)\)) */: Unmatched ')'`

Comment: Thanks it was that parenthesis at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
text.replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, "<span class='font-weight-bold underline'>$1</span>");
```

Comment: $1 should represent the text in the parenthases. In this case it replaces the text with $1.